# getting the value of the last value of the multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have sn array of values, for each month of the last few months. Each month has the number of enquiries, quotes and orders. I am trying to create an array for each month, and then for said month it will hold the values for enquiries, quotes and orders, so I can then output all 3 values for each month.

My problem is that when I use foreach for `$arr[$y][$m] as $a`, the `$a` does not seem to contain the other array elements of enquiries, quotes or orders, i.e. `$a['enquiries']` yields no value.

How can I obtain the values, or is there a much simpler way of doing this?

```
// creating the array

$arr = array();
$arr[19][03]['enquiries'] = 34;
$arr[19][02]['enquiries'] = 24;
$arr[19][01]['enquiries'] = 28;
$arr[18][12]['enquiries'] = 42;

$arr[19][03]['quotes'] = 22;
$arr[19][02]['quotes'] = 14;
$arr[19][01]['quotes'] = 11;
$arr[18][12]['quotes'] = 23;

$arr[19][03]['orders'] = 15;
$arr[19][02]['orders'] = 9;
$arr[19][01]['orders'] = 6;
$arr[18][12]['orders'] = 11;

// extrapolating the values

$y = 19;
$m = 03;
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {

// outputting the values

    foreach($arr[$y][$m] as $a) {
        echo $y.' '.$m.' enquiries='.$a['enquiries'].'<br>';
        echo $y.' '.$m.' quotes='.$a['quotes'].'<br>';
        echo $y.' '.$m.' orders='.$a['orders'].'<br>';
    }

    // creating the units the previous month

    $m--;
    if($m<1) {
        $m = 12;
        $y = $y--;
    }
}
```

Outputted array:

```
Array
(
    [19] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [enquiries] => 34
                    [quotes] => 22
                    [orders] => 15
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [enquiries] => 24
                    [quotes] => 14
                    [orders] => 9
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [enquiries] => 28
                    [quotes] => 11
                    [orders] => 6
                )

        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [enquiries] => 42
                    [quotes] => 23
                    [orders] => 11
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `foreach`. `$arr[$y][$m]` already points at the array with keys `enquiries` etc. so you can just access the values directly:

```
echo $y.' '.$m.' enquiries='.$arr[$y][$m]['enquiries'].'<br>';
echo $y.' '.$m.' quotes='.$arr[$y][$m]['quotes'].'<br>';
echo $y.' '.$m.' orders='.$arr[$y][$m]['orders'].'<br>';
```

Comment: great much easier, dont know why I thought I needed a foreach in there